# Incremental accumulator by subvectoring

Tags: recursion, clojure

The purpose of the following code is to, given a vector, compute the two accumulators: 1. head-till-nth element, 2. (n+1)th element-till-last (where n, and this is the catch, *iterates from 1 till length-of-list*, inclusive).

```
(let [my-list [1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 6]]
  (loop [elem 0]
    (when (<= elem (count my-list))
      (do        (println (reduce + (take elem my-list)))
                 (println (reduce + (drop elem my-list)))
                 (recur (inc elem))))))
```

While this code gets the job done, it is not functional but rather imperative (using a local, *elem*, as a running index and comparing against the vector's length to determine termination).

I considered using `doseq` but I can see no immediate way to *incrementally* slice the vector per the requirements. Using `for` is also wrong as I'm not trying to create a list comprehension.

I'd appreciate any answer showing the *idiomatic* Clojure way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To code in a more functional style, break it down starting with the smallest pieces.  I would do it like this:

```
(defn head-accum [n coll]
  (reduce + (take n coll)))

(defn tail-accum [n coll]
  (reduce + (drop n coll)))

(defn pair-accum [n coll]
  [ (head-accum n coll)
    (tail-accum n coll) ] )

(defn all-pair-accum [coll]
  (let [n-vals (count coll) ]
    (for [split-val (range 1 n-vals) ]
      (pair-accum split-val coll))))

(println (all-pair-accum (range 11)))

;=> ([0 55] [1 54] [3 52] [6 49] [10 45] [15 40] [21 34] [28 27] [36 19] [45 10])
```

Comment: Great. Thank you! Nice seeing how you COULD (and did) use `for` comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not *much* of an improvement, but at least this way we let the sequence determine when the loop ends and not some imperative comparison against *the sequence's lenght.*
(Also got rid of the explicit `let` when `loop` implements it implicitly).

```
(loop [i 1 vtr [1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 0]]
  (when (seq (drop (- i 1) vtr))
    (reduce + (take i vtr))
    (reduce + (drop i vtr))
    (recur (inc i) vtr)))
```